# Why does ldd fail to find libstdc++ in /usr/local/lib64 without LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, ld, ldd

I would like to run a program compiled with gcc-11 on a raspberry pi 4b without having to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH or having to link with the library path.

At the moment, if I have to specity the path to the new libstdc++ in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, otherwise ld fails to load the correct library:

```
pi@cm4:~ $ ./rckam-server --version
./rckam-server: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.13' not found (required by ./rckam-server)
./rckam-server: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by ./rckam-server)
./rckam-server: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./rckam-server)
pi@cm4:~ $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64 ./rckam-server --version
rckam-server version 0.2021.08.23-a5d7a165
pi@cm4:~ $
```

I am running Raspberry Pi OS 64 bits (debian 10.11). After building and installing gcc 11.2.0, I have created /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc-11.2.0.conf:

```
pi@cm4:/etc $ cat ld.so.conf.d/gcc-11.2.0.conf
/usr/local/libexec/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0
/usr/local/lib64

pi@cm4:/etc $
```

After running ldconfig I verified that the cache contains the relevant libraries:

```
pi@cm4:/etc $ ldconfig -p | grep libstdc++
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,AArch64) => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so (libc6,AArch64) => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so
pi@cm4:/etc $ ldconfig -p | grep liblto
    liblto_plugin.so (libc6,AArch64) => /usr/local/libexec/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0/liblto_plugin.so
pi@cm4:/etc $
```

This is the compiler:

```
pi@cm4:/etc $ gcc-11 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-11
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-11.2.0/configure -v --enable-languages=c,c++ --program-suffix=-11 --with-cpu=cortex-a72
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)
```

What else should I do to enable ld to find the appriopriate libraries in /usr/local/lib64?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure that the newer version of libstdc++ is considered before the old one. This is exactly what happens when LS_LIBRARY_PATH is specified.

The output of "ldconfig -p | grep libstdc++" lists /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 after /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 and that is where the problem lies. It happens because the file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/aarch64-linux-gnu.conf is processed by ldconfig before /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc-11.0.2.conf.

There are several ways to control the order in which the directories are processed by ldconfig. The first one is the old fashioned method: listing the directories in the desired order directly in /etc/ld.so.conf instead of using gcc-11.2.0.conf. Something like this:

```
/usr/local/libexec/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0
/usr/local/lib64
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

The file gcc-11.2.0.conf can be explicitly included before the generic include (it doesn't matter if a file is included twice):

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc-11.2.0.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

When using files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d, it is also possible to control the order of the includes with numeric prefixes. In this specific case, renaming the file to /etc/ld.so.conf/00-gcc-11.2.0.conf would force ldconfig to process it before any other file in the directory.